# How to detect whether backspace event was single word or character?

Tags: javascript, events, keycode

I have some code to detect whether a backspace event was triggered by a keyboard

```
  if (isKeydown) {
    if (e.which == 8) {
      //backspace
      self.textTracker.updateTextByBackspace(startIndex, endIndex);
    }}
```

What is the best way to detect whether this was a single word or single character delete?

For example: CTRL+bckspce on windows does the same thing as ALT+bckspce on osx (deletes an entire word).

I can trivially detect whether the alt or control key was pressed with the backspace key. From there, I could check the operating system for windows/mac and put the pieces together.

Is this the most reliable way of doing this?